# wordpress custom orderby statement

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am trying to display a custom post type list ordered by a value that is located in its own table. I am using a plugin called wti_like_posts, which allows for users to rate posts via thumbs up/down manner.

The table contains the score and post_id attached to it. I would like to be able to add to the already existing options for 'orderby' in the query an option 'rating', so it could take that score into consideration when I query posts.

Do you know any good way to do so ? I guess I have to use add_filter, but I already tried and cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a custom sql query to join both the tables to get your results.

```
global $wpdb; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wp_posts, ".$wpdb->prefix."ratings_table WHERE wp_post.id = ratings_table.post_id";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($posts as $post){
    echo '<li>'.$post->title.'|'.$post->score.'<br/>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Not tested!

You will have to adjust the tables & column names.

[update]
ok to use get_posts() you have to change your orderby=rating&meta_key=foo
to orderby=meta_value&meta_key=rating

see below:

```
$args = array(
 'numberposts'     => 10,
 'offset'          => 0,
 'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
 'order'           => 'ASC', 
 'meta_key'        => 'rating', 
 'post_type'       => 'post',
 'post_status'     => 'publish' 
 );
 $results = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I already managed to get a list running, using this method. But the thing is I would like to add that orderby options to the wordpress ones, so I can use it with i.e.  `get_posts('post_type=type&num_posts=10&orderby=rating&meta_key=foo[...]')` . Because I'd like to use it to filter results with different parameters (taxonomies, searches, authors, etc...) dynamically...

Comment: The thing is, the value I want is not located in the wp_postmeta table, it is in its own table... That is why I cannot use this method... the `meta_key=foo` was just as an example, because i wanted to show you that i had many parameters already in my requests, just ignore it...